# SQL query to remove certain text from each field in a specific column - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to convert the following:

```
*----*----------------------------*
| id | file_id                  
*----*----------------------------*    
| 1  | 128804/12/0 
*----*----------------------------*
| 2  | 128876/15/0 
*----*----------------------------*
```

Into the following:

```
*----*----------------------------*
| id | file_id                
*----*----------------------------*    
| 1  | 128804    
*----*----------------------------*
| 2  | 128876   
*----*----------------------------*
```

So it only gives out the first 6 characters for each field in a column (the column has many more entries). I need a select and not to rewrite the table. Anyone know how?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `substr()`

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a4d2d822839491ed56b9e1e00511bdb5)**

```
select substr(file_id,0,INSTR(file_id, '/')-1)
```

OUTPUT:

```
VAL
128804
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple method is `regexp_substr()`:

```
select t.*, regexp_substr(file_id, '^[0-9]+') as file_id
from t;
```

This returns the leading digits from the column value.

Answer (score 1):

```
with s (id, file_id) as (
select 1, '128804/12/0'   from dual union all
select 2, '128876/15/0'   from dual union all
select 3, '128876'        from dual union all
select 4, '128876/128876' from dual)
select id, file_id,
regexp_substr (file_id, '[^/]+') as file_id_sub_1,
regexp_replace(file_id, '/.*')   as file_id_sub_2
from s;

        ID FILE_ID       FILE_ID_SUB_1   FILE_ID_SUB_2
---------- ------------- --------------- ---------------
         1 128804/12/0   128804          128804
         2 128876/15/0   128876          128876
         3 128876        128876          128876
         4 128876/128876 128876          128876
```